# Transfer ERC20 token without ETH

Tags: ethereum, erc20, go-ethereum

I would like to transfer ERC20 tokens from a wallet who don't own ETH to another wallet who own ETH and who can pay gas fee.
Do you know if it is possible to made a transfer of ERC20 tokens and to let the receiver wallet pay fees ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: Not possible, unless the token contract explicitly allows it. Or unless the token holder is also the block producer.

Transaction fees are paid in ETH (or generally, native currency of the network - for example BNB on Binance Smart Chain, MATIC on Polygon, ...). So in most cases, you need to pay ETH to execute either the `transfer()` function if you want to send the tokens from your address, or the `approve()` function if you want someone else to transfer tokens from your address.

Very few token contracts implement delegated transfer mechanism on top of the ERC20 standard. There's currently no standardized way to perform a delegated transfer, so each contract might have a different implementation. The token holder uses their private key to sign a predetermined message saying how many tokens they want to transfer to which address. The message also usually contains a nonce or a timestamp to prevent [signature replay](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-121) attack. Token holder passes the message offchain to the transaction sender, and then the transaction sender executes a function of the token contract built specifically for delegated transfers (note that the transaction sender pays the fee to execute this function). The contract validates the signature, and performs the transfer. Again, most token contracts **do not** implement this mechanism.

One more exception from the rule is a block producer. When you create a new block, you can fill it with transactions not only from the mempool but also with your own transactions. You can build a transaction with 0 gas price, and then include it in the block that you're producing. This way you're also able to send tokens for free.

Comment: I landed here while looking for the EIP that proposed a standard around this mechanism. Would you happen to know the EIP number?

Comment: @Mouradif You probably mean [EIP-4337 Account Abstraction](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4337). It is currently (August 2023) not finalized but several EVM networks already allow processing User Operations that consist of the following scenario: Address A pays transaction fee in ETH; address B is the token sender and pays to Address A in stablecoin or any other ERC-20 token. So effectively Address B doesn't spend any ETH for transfer of their tokens... My original answer was written when this EIP was in very early stage and I wasn't even aware of this standard being discussed at the time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Petr Hejda Actually I was talking about [EIP-2612](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612).

Comment: @Mouradif Awesome, thank you for the clarification. EIP-2612 in fact standardizes the way how tokens can be transferred without the token sender paying any transaction fees. Unlike Account Abstraction, token contracts still need to explicitly implement the EIP-2612 mechanism in order to be able to make use of this feature.

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for. It's for a token I'm developing. I'm aware of Account Abstraction. If you're interested in that topic, I suggest you check out Lukso's take on the subject with Universal Accounts. It's developped by one of the creators of ERC-20 and ERC-725.